# R - plotting two time series only shows the first one

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot two time series using the following code:

```
yq <- zoo::as.yearqtr(df1$var1)
plot(yq, df1$var2, type = "l", col = "red")
lines(df1$var3, col = "blue")
```

but it only plots the first time series (var2). How can I plot the second one as well in the same graph?

Here is my dataset:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(var1 = c("2012Q1", "2012Q2", "2012Q3", "2012Q4", 
"2013Q1", "2013Q2", "2013Q3", "2013Q4", "2014Q1", "2014Q2", "2014Q3", 
"2014Q4", "2015Q1", "2015Q2", "2015Q3", "2015Q4", "2016Q1", "2016Q2", 
"2016Q3", "2016Q4", "2017Q1", "2017Q2", "2017Q3", "2017Q4", "2018Q1", 
"2018Q2", "2018Q3", "2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2"), var2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 444618.290581211, 1556125.2312821, 744145.122633215, 
844862.245210837, 773188.163309878, 1204732.23940684, 1832308.19798703, 
1732186.62322613, 1475089.69403864, 1238791.22680584, 772358.984604352, 
927111.535808541, 982978.903715697, 581415.120412662, 489457.818616084, 
446419.025443493, 403840.992700758, 654630.928503824, 753729.397874631, 
513754.997587623, 587031.503365487, 465808.650890606, 462710.391792817, 
537923.914536013, 409037.838465172, 785118.681845306), var3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3544407.49, NA, NA, NA, 5254709.85, NA, NA, NA, 4430302.745, 
NA, NA, NA, 2499437.24, NA, NA, NA, 2216217.61, NA, NA, NA, 2024459.22, 
NA, NA, NA, 2537232.26, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try `lines(yq, df1$var3, col = "blue")` Please read the manuals.

Comment: You have NAs between the numbers in `var3` and the lines cannot be created. Try `plot(yq, df1$var3);
plot(yq, df1$var3, type = "l")` to see the difference.

Comment: still not working @zx8754

Comment: Try this: `yq <- zoo::as.yearqtr(df1$var1);
plot(yq, df1$var2, type = "l", col = "red", ylim = c(0, max(c(max(df1$var2, na.rm = T), 
                                                              max(df1$var3, na.rm = T)))));
lines(yq[!is.na(df1$var3)], df1$var3[!is.na(df1$var3)], col = "blue")` as you need to adjust the y axis limit, but also remove any NA values from `var3`.

Comment: @AntoniosK it works excellent. Please post it as a reply below and I will accept your answers. many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yq <- zoo::as.yearqtr(df1$var1)

# plot var2 and set the limit of y axis
plot(yq, df1$var2, type = "l", col = "red", ylim = c(min(c(df1$var2, df1$var3), na.rm = T), 
                                                     max(c(df1$var2, df1$var3), na.rm = T)))
# plot var3 after removing any NAs
lines(yq[!is.na(df1$var3)], df1$var3[!is.na(df1$var3)], col = "blue")
```

[image]

You can also remove NAs from `var2` in a similar way, so your plot starts from `2013` on the x axis.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks (Ελλαδάρα! :))

Answer (score 1):

Convert df1 to a zoo object and then you can do it in one plot call.  Use `na.approx` to ensure that NAs do not break up the plot.  Omit `screen=1` if you want multiple panels. (continued after graphic)

```
library(zoo)

z1 <- read.zoo(df1, FUN = as.yearqtr)

cols <- c("red", "blue")
plot(na.approx(z1), col = cols, screen = 1, xlab = "", ylab = "")
legend("topright", names(z1), col = cols, lty = 1)
```

[image: screenshot]

Alternately we could use lattice or ggplot2:

```
library(lattice)
key <- list(space = "right", text = list(names(z1)), lines = list(col = cols))
xyplot(na.approx(z1), xlab = "", col = cols, screen = 1, key = key)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(na.approx(z1), facet = NULL) + xlab("")
```